# What is the use of member initializers list in constructors?

Tags: c++, member-initialization

I was trying to understand the concept of operator overloading, but can't understand the use of member initializer lists in this program. What is their real use, and could I rewrite this program without them ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Complex
{
    private:
  float real;
  float imag;
    public:
   Complex(): real(0), imag(0){ }
   void input()
   {
       cout<<"Enter real and imaginary parts respectively: ";
       cin>>real;
       cin>>imag;
   }
   Complex operator - (Complex c2)    /* Operator Function */
   {
       Complex temp;
       temp.real=real-c2.real;
       temp.imag=imag-c2.imag;
       return temp;
   }
   void output()
   {
       if(imag<0)
           cout<<"Output Complex number: "<<real<<imag<<"i";
       else
           cout<<"Output Complex number: "<<real<<"+"<<imag<<"i";
   }
};
int main()
{
Complex c1, c2, result;
cout<<"Enter first complex number:\n";
c1.input();
cout<<"Enter second complex number:\n";
c2.input();
result=c1-c2; 
result.output();
return 0;
```

Comment: The initializer list has nothing to do with the operator overload. Maybe others can help to clarify if you tell us why you think this would be the case.

Comment: btw you have a `"-"` missing on the output of negative imaginaries

Answer (score 3):

I think there is some kind of confusion. You are not talking about [std::initialize_list](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) but rather [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Yes you can write your constructor without using it :

```
Complex(): real(0), imag(0){ }
```

becomes :

```
Complex(): { real=0; image=0; }
```

However I would not recommend it. See [here why](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists).

Comment: NB: You can, but shouldn't if you can avoid it, because you then perform a default-initialization followed by an assignment.

Comment: @coincoin I am talking about member initializer list here

Comment: oh okay! yeah assignment will also be there if we don't  use initializer list here. Actually I am new to all these types of concepts Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Question edited to clarify that it's about member initialization, not `std::initializer_list`, and overloading isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is small in this case, but becomes very significant when the members to be initialized are references, or declared `const`.  Then they cannot be assigned, and *must* be initialized.